# Search for all days of a week using dateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, date, sql-server-ce, datepart

I want to retrieve all days of a week, selecting any day of that given week.

Example: Wanna retrieve  31/07/2016 (dd/MM/yyyy) to 06/08/2016 (dd/MM/yyyy)

Ocurrences by selecting any day of the presented week.

Is it possible?

My current code:

```
private void AutoLoadCalendar()
        {

            string constringF = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
            string QueryF = "select * from Funcionarios  where (status = N'Ativo') and datepart(year, datafimcontrato) = @ano and datepart(month, datafimcontrato) = @mes ";
            SqlCeConnection conDataBaseF = new SqlCeConnection(constringF);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBaseF = new SqlCeCommand(QueryF, conDataBaseF);
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@mes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Month);
            cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@ano", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Year);
            try
            {


                SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBaseF;


                System.Data.DataTable dbdatasetF = new System.Data.DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdatasetF);
                BindingSource bSourceF = new BindingSource();

                bSourceF.DataSource = dbdatasetF;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSourceF;
                sda.Update(dbdatasetF);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Where are you dealing with dates in your code? Or should I say where are you trying to do this in your code snippet?

Comment: dateparts and monthcalendar

Comment: Put solutions in the answer block below, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Best regards

You can use the DATEPART function to know witch day of the week has your selected date and knowing that number is easy to solve your problem n___n

Try with this:

```
private void AutoLoadCalendar()
    {

        string constringF = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\cadastramentodb.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
        string QueryF = 
            "DECLARE @DiaSemana AS INT " +
            "SET @DiaSemana=DATEPART(DW,@Fecha) " +
            " " +
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM Funcionarios " +
            "WHERE [status] = N'Ativo' AND datafimcontrato >= DATEADD(DD,@DiaSemana*-1,@Fecha) AND datafimcontrato <= DATEADD(DD,7-@DiaSemana,@Fecha) ";
        SqlCeConnection conDataBaseF = new SqlCeConnection(constringF);
        SqlCeCommand cmdDataBaseF = new SqlCeCommand(QueryF, conDataBaseF);
        cmdDataBaseF.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", monthCalendar1.Value);
        try
        {
            SqlCeDataAdapter sda = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBaseF;

            System.Data.DataTable dbdatasetF = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdatasetF);
            BindingSource bSourceF = new BindingSource();

            bSourceF.DataSource = dbdatasetF;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSourceF;
            sda.Update(dbdatasetF);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```